# Python's Django could not connect to Oracle 11g

Tags: django, oracle11g, database-connection, python-2.7

I am a newbie to Python trying out to quickly build a site using Django.

Following are the steps I have performed (Win 7):

- Installed Python 2.7
- Installed Django 1.4
- Created a project and app
- Started the server using '`python manage.py startserver`' and accessed using the "http://127.0.0.1:8000" the basic page.
- Now wanted to configure my Oracle 11g DB for my project. Hence, installed `cx_Oracle 5.1-11g` and tried '`python manage.py syncdb`' which failed with **cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24315: illegal attribute type**.
- Got the same error even from a python interpretor.

  ```
  import cx_Oracle
   connection=cx_Oracle.Connection('python_user','python_user','(DESC..string..)')
  ```

---

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24315: illegal attribute type
```

- I am using the correct credentials and libraries as per my trouble shooting.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Checking *which* attribute is failing by raising an explicit exception might help you in the right direction

```
try:
    connection=cx_Oracle.Connection('python_user','python_user','(DESC..string..)')
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, e:
    print e[0].context
    raise
```

Comment: 'ERROR: Connection_Connect(): set driver name' was the context.

Comment: I reckon it's an issue with the cx_Oracle build. Are you sure it was compiled against the Oracle 11g client?
There's a similar issue here: http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ora-24315%20error%3A%20connection_connect()%3A%20set%20driver%20name&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcomments.gmane.org%2Fgmane.comp.python.db.cx-oracle%2F2111&ei=La-OT_uEJIicOvjewNMK&usg=AFQjCNFeIW9_BjE-2nCT1lPCFu2Hae5xFQ

Comment: quote: 'Its not the Oracle client that I am concerned with. It
is the version of cx_Oracle that you are using! You need to make sure that the version of cx_Oracle you are using was compiled against Oracle 10g and it appears to have been compiled with an Oracle 11g client.' How can I make sure this is compiled against 11g in my case? I got the msi file from http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think I found the issue! My system has a 10.2 version of Oracle Xe installed. May be thats the problem. I will install a 11g version, update the PATH envi' variable and check.

Comment: I think this fixed the problem. But with 11g version I get this error. 'cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle'. Getting pissed off with this... :-x

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is versions of the following should be compatible with each other.

`Python 2.7`, `Django 1.4`, `Oracle DB 11g (which I connect to)` and lib `cx_Oracle 5.0.3+-11g` should be in compatible with `Oracle Xe 11.2` (which was 10.2 previously).

After installing the right version and setting the ORACLE_HOME to '`C:/oraclexe/.../11.2.0/server`' it started connecting without any issues.